# Does a man get punished in hell for not loving all his wives equally?

Tags: marriage, hell, wife

Hinduism allow polygyny for men . But Does a man get punished in hell for not loving all his wives equally ?

Comment: If you think Hinduism supports polygamy, please reference a quote from the vedas.

Comment: Chandra Dev got messed up by Bholenath & Prajapati Daksh in some stories, cause he married several sisters & only gave attention to Rohini. Which was not fair to his other wives, though obviously so many of these stories are meant in different ways. I think there is weird bewilderment for many folks, as some Hindu stuff that seems outlandish is actually quite matter of fact. While other stuff that people take literally, is meant to be parabolic. So then, understandable that many folks are perplexed, this is just my opinion.)